# jquery in viewport checker for multiple elements at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery function that checks if an element is in the viewport or not. If it is it adds the class 'animate' to start an animation and make the element visible.

The above works, but right now ( with multiple elements ) jQuery only targets the first element with the class `blogcard`. And then executes the `addClass("animate")` for all elements. I want it to look for each element if it is in the viewport. perhaps with the `jQuery.each()` function. But I haven't managed to get that working yet.

This is my code:

JS:

```
$.fn.isInViewport = function () {
    let elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    let elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
    let viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    let viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

$(window).on("load resize scroll", function () {
    if ($('.blogcard ').isInViewport()) {
        $('.blogcard').addClass("animate");
        console.log('success.')
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.fade-in {
    opacity            : 0;
    -webkit-transition : opacity 2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition    : opacity 2s ease-in;
    -ms-transition     : opacity 2s ease-in;
    -o-transition      : opacity 2s ease-in;
    transition         : opacity 2s ease-in;
}

.fade-in.animate {
    opacity : 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
{#Item 1#}
<div class="blogcard fade-in">
    {#Blog content#}
</div>
{#Item 2#}
<div class="blogcard fade-in">
    {#Blog content#}
</div>
{#Item 3#}
<div class="blogcard fade-in">
    {#Blog content#}
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can do it with $.each():

```
$(window).on("load resize scroll", function () {
    $('.blogcard').each(function() {
        if( $(this).isInViewport() ) {
            $(this).addClass('animate');
        }
    });
});
```